# How to stop the Apple Music ads every time I launch the Music app?

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-music, music.app

Lately, the Music app on my iPhone XR has been showing the "Join Apple Music!" call-to-action interstitial screen pretty much every time I launch it. Usually this happens when I'm in a bad-network area, too, so it takes a few minutes before it appears, preventing me from playing my locally-stored music and playlists.

I neither have nor want Apple Music, and I have disabled Apple Music on my device through the respective control panel:

[image]

And yet I still get the interstitial ad for Apple Music at least once a week, if not more. Is there any way to disable this "feature?"

Comment: Thanks for the bounty Ring 0 - I’ll try to see if this is a bug (I sure hope it’s a bug so I can edit my answer to explain that directly or a workaround) that you can’t dismiss this.  However, even as someone that subscribes to Apple Music, I can’t imagine only using the native music app. Check out Cs music player, it’s really fabulous and would let you avoid this music ad whether its a bug or intentional on Apple’s part.

Answer (score 2):

I hate to say, but I’ve not been able to find any way to accomplish this so I’m going to recommend just using a different music app with your same music library that the native Music app creates and manages.

For me, I love the Cs music player and it does an amazing job at using your existing music library and lets you avoid using the native app any time it disappoints you.

- [Cs Music Player by Mike Clay](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cs-music-player/id924491991?mt=8)

I think this used to be called the cesium player if you search for other reviews or don’t want to try this app. What it does for me is it knows which songs are Apple Music and coached locally, so I don’t incur data charges and just want to shuffle songs I already downloaded. I also prefer this app over Apple for several local library situations (classical music, better for me interface, etc...)

Comment: Interesting. The app's FAQ at https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cs-music-player/id924491991?mt=8 indicates that it supports all of the stuff I care about, too... I'll consider this!

Comment: Er, actual FAQ link: http://www.csmusicplayer.com/faq